# R - figuring out what columns an xgboost model is expecting in new data for predictions

Tags: r, xgboost

We have a `.model` file that has an xgboost model. Here's a snippet of our code loading the model:

```
> xg_model <- xgb.load("../model_outputs/our_saved_model.model")
> xg_model
##### xgb.Booster
raw: 1.6 Mb 
xgb.attributes:
  niter
niter: 149
```

I didn't create this model, but I am tasked with passing new data to the model in order to make predictions. Unfortunately, I am hitting this error:

```
Error in predict.xgb.Booster(xg_model, xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(our_dataframe_of_data))) : 
  [01:34:01] amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:1183: Check failed: learner_model_param_.num_feature >= p_fmat->Info().num_col_ (38 vs. 40) : Number of columns does not match number of features in booster.
```

... so it's clear that our dataframe has 40 columns, but this model is trained to expect a dataframe with 38 columns. What's unclear is exactly which 38 columns our `xg_model` is expecting. Is there a function to call / plot to graph / etc. that might show what 38 columns the model was trained on? We only have the trained model currently, but not the `R` code that trained the model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your XGBoost version? It's important to know, because XGBoost "schema specification" has been evolving quite significantly.

Right now, you should explore what attributes are available on your `xgb.Booster` object. See if it has `nfeatures` and `feature_names` attributes defined:

```
print(xg_model$nfeatures)
print(xg_model$feature_names)
```

I believe your `xgb.Booster` object has these attributes available, because how else would it know to demand 38 features?

Comment: I don't know how to check my xgboost version, but I cannot print these features. The only available elements on `xg_model$` are `handle`, `raw`, and `niter`

Comment: when loading the model i do get a warning `[20:30:11] WARNING: amalgamation/../src/learner.cc:790: Loading model from XGBoost < 1.0.0, consider saving it again for improved compatibility` so perhaps i need to hunt down the code that created this model and re-run it.

Comment: If the model was created/saved with a pre-1.0.0 version, then perhaps it would be easiest to reinstall an "appropriately outdated" xgboost package version? For example, the 0.90 version. Older package versions don't perform schema checks.

Comment: It seems like the best solution may just be to refit the model, with the model training code that I've now got.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was able to solve it after extracting the model features like this.

`ModelVars<- xgb.importance(feature_names = colnames(our_dataframe_of_data),model=xg_model)`

After this it was just a matter of subsetting my dataframe to the ones in ModelVars. I was able to use predict function and get the scores even though the number of features was less than the number of features in the training dataset as expected.